# SSMS: Database could not be detected as it is linked. Make sure that the user has linked a database to source control

Tags: sql-server, ssms, redgate, source-control-bindings, readyroll

My colleague has tried RedGate's product "Ready Roll" on our database which is also linked to Sql Source Control (also RedGate). After he uninstalled Ready Roll, none of us (him nor the rest of our team) can alter any stored procedures or make changes to the database any more.

Management Studio just shows a blank error pane with this text:

```
Database could not be detected as it is linked. Make sure that the user has linked a database to source control
```

Some of us have tried unlinking and relinking the database to Sql Source Control, but without success.

Any ideas on how to restore our ability to develop on the database again?

Comment: It's unlikely that the error is related to ReadyRoll, given that the tool doesn't link a database schema directly to source control. However if you're looking to remove all traces of ReadyRoll from your schema, you may want to clean up these objects: __MigrationLog (table) and __MigrationLogCurrent (view)

Comment: @DanNolan, you are correct. The same colleague was also testing ApexSQL Source Control on another database (but on the same server). After he unlinked it, everything was back to normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you also make use of ApexSQL Source Control and using the shared development model? Unlink the ApexSQL DB.